# How to know the status of a process started with "cmd start"?

Tags: java, process

I am trying to write a small tool that restarts a certain number of jar's if they have been terminated.

```
private static void checkAndRestartProcesses() {
    for ( int i=0; i<processes.size(); i++ ) {
        try {
            processes.get(i).exitValue();
            processes.remove(i);
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException ex) {
        }
    }
    try {
        for ( int i=processes.size(); i<Config.NR_PROCESSES; i++ ) {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c start cmd /c java -jar bla.jar");
            Process p = pb.start();
            processes.add(p);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

The problem is that processes started with "cmd start" exit right after they execute the sub-process (and thus, there is no IllegalThreadStateException).
How can I keep track of the subprocess (whether they are terminated or not)?
Or alternatively: How can I start a sub-process in a separate cmd without using "cmd start".
I need the started routines to be in a new cmd.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: why are you using `cmd /c start ___` here instead of `___`?

Comment: i want to have a separate cmd window for each of the processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the /wait flag on start

```
cmd /c start /wait java -jar bla.jar
```

Comment: this is awesome ... exactly what i wanted to know. thank you tons.